# How to map an entity from external bundle to user entity

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to create a reusable bundle for Symfony projects.

This bundle has a huge model mapping, but I encounter a conceptual problem :

How, with Symfony, can I bind one of my entities to the user entity of the final application of the people using the bundle ?

Can I use some configuration to get the user class and dynamically create the mapping between those two classes or is there a better approach of this matter ?

Thank you community :) !

Comment: I'd recommend looking into how other large bundles does similar things.  One simple example could be [FOSCommentBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle). Basically create abstract base entities (with mapping data) that the people using the bundle will then extend in their apps.

Comment: Yes, I knew this way of doing things ! I will try to make it without big constraints for the end-user !

Comment: I understand, but keeping it similar to other known bundles make it easy to adopt your bundle as well. In addition having an `AppBundle:Entity` that extend `YourBundle:BaseEntity` makes it mure more clear what's going on. Some like to keep the amount of "magic" to a minimum ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I wanted something like this : https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/

This is surely the solution I will apply to my project.

After a few days of developement, I noticed that for each new entity I create, I must map it to a "end-user extendable" class of the bundle. If I tell the end-user to map himself the Project class to his own User class, I later have to tell him "Each class which is mapped to the Project class must be also manually mapped".

I think none of us wants to implement an external bundle and override each part of its internal model. Dynamic mapping with event subscribers avoids it !

Ty for your help, I hope this note will help some other lads :D !